# When calling a member function, why is it different whether the object is added with a "&" or not?

Tags: c++

Recently, I am learning to use the C++ STL for concurrent programming, and I am reading the book "C++ Concurrency in Action, 2nd Edition".

In the code list 4.7 of section 4.2.1 of the book, there is a piece of code that uses std::async to call member functions. Two methods are used when passing class objects, one is to pass pointer, and the other is to pass directly.

The book makes comments on the operation effects of the two methods, among which the class object is copied when passing directly, but not when passing pointer.

```
//Listing 4.7 Passing arguments to a function with std::async

#include <string>
#include <future>
struct X
{
 void foo(int,std::string const&);
 std::string bar(std::string const&);
};
X x;
auto f1=std::async(&X::foo,&x,42,"hello"); //Calls p->foo(42,"hello"), where p is &x
auto f2=std::async(&X::bar,x,"goodbye");   //Calls tmpx.bar("goodbye"), where tmpx is a copy of x
```

I don't understand why two methods will bring different results. Is it related to whether the parameter is an rvalue, or because of some other reason, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

> auto f1=std::async(&X::foo,&x,42,"hello");

you pass a pointer to `x` so the function `X::foo` will be called on the `x` class instance from you code example.

In this code:

> auto f2=std::async(&X::bar,x,"goodbye");

you pass an object itself, std::async will make a temporary of that object and call `X::bar` on it. Actually it will copy `x` multiple times - thats how std::async works. You can use `std::ref` to eliminate copies:

> auto f2=std::async(&X::bar,std::ref(x),"goodbye");